# Error in Instagram API

Tags: asp.net, instagram-api

I am using asp vb.net and instagram api.

I found a [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Haroon-Said-e1d8d388) on instagram api but it is in c#. I tried to convert from c# to VB the best I could but for some reason I am getting an error.

> Error: The Remote Server Returned An Error 400 Bad Request

I am getting an error on line:

```
Dim result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", parameters)
```

My code:

```
Function GetDataInstagramToken()
Try
    Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection
    parameters.Add("client_id", Client_ID)
    parameters.Add("client_secret", ClientSecret)
    parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8979/UI/InstaHome.aspx")
    parameters.Add("code", Code)

    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", parameters)
    Dim response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result)

    'deserializing nested JSON string to object
    Dim jsResult As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response)
    Dim accessToken As String = jsResult("access_token")
    Dim id As Int16 = jsResult("user")("id")

    'This code register id and access token to get on client side
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String()), "GetToken", "<script>var instagramaccessid=\"" + @"" + id + "" + " \ "; var instagramaccesstoken=\"" + @"" + accessToken + "" + " \ ";</script>")

Catch ex As Exception
     myLabel.text += "-" &ex.message
End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Check My Answer I use It, It Should Work

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "post", parameters);
```

> You don't send any value to Instagram. If you check your
>   parameter, you can see your key but you Can't see any
>   value.

Try this:

```
public async void GetTokenFromCode()
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>    {
          { "client_id","Your ChatId" },
          { "client_secret", "Your Client Secret" },
          { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
          { "redirect_uri", "Your Redirect url"},
          { "code", "code" }    };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```